# Do store auto-subscription work even if there's no $ reference at the top level of a component?

Tags: svelte

According to the [tutorial](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions):

> Auto-subscription only works with store variables that are declared (or imported) at the top-level scope of a component.

This leads me to believe if you have a page and import a `user` store like so:

```
<script>
import { user } from "$stores/auth";
function doSomething() {
    const response = fetch('www.someurl.com').then(response => {
        console.log($user);
    });
}
</script>
```

then this should still result in auto-subscription?

The tutorial seems to imply that `auto-subscription` will always happen if a store variable is imported at the top-level, which it is here. If that's the case, even if there was no `doSomething()` function and no reference to `$user` anywhere in the code here or the HTML below, would auto-subscription still happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A usage of the `$`-syntax causes a subscription, not the creation or import of the store. So unless `$user` is used anywhere, there will be no subscription.

The documentation merely points out that stores declared in other places, e.g. on items in an array cannot be auto-subscribed to, you will get errors. Related GitHub issue: [#4079](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4079)

(The given code will work since the import is at the top level.)

Comment: I see. So it's the fact that the import is at the top level AND that `$user` is referenced anywhere in the script (or HTML, which does not exist in this case)?

Comment: The `$` instructs it to auto-subscribe, the top level is just a requirement, and if that is not met, you simply get a compiler error.